# How to identify a directory in getBlobList request in Azure Data Lake

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-data-lake

I am making a get Blob list call to a container in Azure Data Lake Storage having both blobs and directories in it.

The request looks like this:

```
{
  url: 'https://{account}.blob.core.windows.net/container-1?comp=list&restype=container&prefix=directory-1/&maxresults=100',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'x-ms-date': 'Tue, 18 Jan 2022 05:58:28 GMT',
    'x-ms-version': '2019-02-02',
    Authorization: 'Bearer {Token}'
  }
}
```

and the response looks something like this:

```
{
"EnumerationResults": {
    "Prefix": "directory-1/",
    "MaxResults": "100",
    "Blobs": {
        "Blob": [
            {
                "Name": "directory-1/directory1-1",
                "Properties": {
                    "Creation-Time": "Wed, 12 Jan 2022 10:56:50 GMT",
                    "Last-Modified": "Wed, 12 Jan 2022 10:56:50 GMT",
                    "Etag": "0x8D9D5BA3C8CC53E",
                    "Content-Length": "0",
                    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
                    "Content-Encoding": "",
                    "Content-Language": "",
                    "Content-CRC64": "AAAAAAAAAAA=",
                    "Content-MD5": "",
                    "Cache-Control": "",
                    "Content-Disposition": "",
                    "BlobType": "BlockBlob",
                    "AccessTier": "Hot",
                    "AccessTierInferred": "true",
                    "LeaseStatus": "unlocked",
                    "LeaseState": "available",
                    "ServerEncrypted": "true"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "directory-1/directory1-1/file1-1-1.csv",
                "Properties": {
                    "Creation-Time": "Thu, 13 Jan 2022 13:08:34 GMT",
                    "Last-Modified": "Thu, 13 Jan 2022 13:08:34 GMT",
                    "Etag": "0x8D9D695CDD159F1",
                    "Content-Length": "80205",
                    "Content-Type": "text/csv",
                    "Content-Encoding": "",
                    "Content-Language": "",
                    "Content-CRC64": "",
                    "Content-MD5": "D/UezNpgI+t6xFpVw3tUGA==",
                    "Cache-Control": "",
                    "Content-Disposition": "",
                    "BlobType": "BlockBlob",
                    "AccessTier": "Hot",
                    "AccessTierInferred": "true",
                    "LeaseStatus": "unlocked",
                    "LeaseState": "available",
                    "ServerEncrypted": "true"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "directory-1/file1-1.csv",
                "Properties": {
                    "Creation-Time": "Wed, 12 Jan 2022 05:45:28 GMT",
                    "Last-Modified": "Thu, 13 Jan 2022 14:04:43 GMT",
                    "Etag": "0x8D9D69DA5DA0F28",
                    "Content-Length": "65",
                    "Content-Type": "text/csv",
                    "Content-Encoding": "",
                    "Content-Language": "",
                    "Content-CRC64": "",
                    "Content-MD5": "Xqyu+Y7Jhxu2n7INUROqNg==",
                    "Cache-Control": "",
                    "Content-Disposition": "",
                    "BlobType": "BlockBlob",
                    "AccessTier": "Hot",
                    "AccessTierInferred": "true",
                    "LeaseStatus": "unlocked",
                    "LeaseState": "available",
                    "ServerEncrypted": "true"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "directory-1/file1-2.json",
                "Properties": {
                    "Creation-Time": "Wed, 12 Jan 2022 05:45:28 GMT",
                    "Last-Modified": "Thu, 13 Jan 2022 14:07:17 GMT",
                    "Etag": "0x8D9D69E01C01B66",
                    "Content-Length": "414",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Content-Encoding": "",
                    "Content-Language": "",
                    "Content-CRC64": "",
                    "Content-MD5": "xxdWz9XwRegDoYI+OrG6tg==",
                    "Cache-Control": "",
                    "Content-Disposition": "",
                    "BlobType": "BlockBlob",
                    "AccessTier": "Hot",
                    "AccessTierInferred": "true",
                    "LeaseStatus": "unlocked",
                    "LeaseState": "available",
                    "ServerEncrypted": "true"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "directory-1/file1-3.jpeg",
                "Properties": {
                    "Creation-Time": "Wed, 12 Jan 2022 05:45:28 GMT",
                    "Last-Modified": "Wed, 12 Jan 2022 05:45:28 GMT",
                    "Etag": "0x8D9D58EBD29AFA4",
                    "Content-Length": "172946",
                    "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
                    "Content-Encoding": "",
                    "Content-Language": "",
                    "Content-CRC64": "",
                    "Content-MD5": "JVLMabvgKvlALNE4V/7eaA==",
                    "Cache-Control": "",
                    "Content-Disposition": "",
                    "BlobType": "BlockBlob",
                    "AccessTier": "Hot",
                    "AccessTierInferred": "true",
                    "LeaseStatus": "unlocked",
                    "LeaseState": "available",
                    "ServerEncrypted": "true"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "directory-1/test",
                "Properties": {
                    "Creation-Time": "Thu, 13 Jan 2022 08:56:13 GMT",
                    "Last-Modified": "Thu, 13 Jan 2022 08:56:13 GMT",
                    "Etag": "0x8D9D6728D3B1933",
                    "Content-Length": "0",
                    "Content-Type": "",
                    "Content-Encoding": "",
                    "Content-Language": "",
                    "Content-CRC64": "",
                    "Content-MD5": "",
                    "Cache-Control": "",
                    "Content-Disposition": "",
                    "BlobType": "BlockBlob",
                    "AccessTier": "Hot",
                    "AccessTierInferred": "true",
                    "LeaseStatus": "unlocked",
                    "LeaseState": "available",
                    "ServerEncrypted": "true"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "directory-1/test/:file.csv",
                "Properties": {
                    "Creation-Time": "Thu, 13 Jan 2022 08:56:13 GMT",
                    "Last-Modified": "Thu, 13 Jan 2022 08:56:13 GMT",
                    "Etag": "0x8D9D6728D3FD74D",
                    "Content-Length": "14",
                    "Content-Type": "text/csv",
                    "Content-Encoding": "",
                    "Content-Language": "",
                    "Content-CRC64": "",
                    "Content-MD5": "0X493GkdoXENg7klv3zR8g==",
                    "Cache-Control": "",
                    "Content-Disposition": "",
                    "BlobType": "BlockBlob",
                    "AccessTier": "Hot",
                    "AccessTierInferred": "true",
                    "LeaseStatus": "unlocked",
                    "LeaseState": "available",
                    "ServerEncrypted": "true"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "directory-1/test/file.csv",
                "Properties": {
                    "Creation-Time": "Thu, 13 Jan 2022 08:59:10 GMT",
                    "Last-Modified": "Thu, 13 Jan 2022 08:59:10 GMT",
                    "Etag": "0x8D9D672F701A8DA",
                    "Content-Length": "14",
                    "Content-Type": "text/csv",
                    "Content-Encoding": "",
                    "Content-Language": "",
                    "Content-CRC64": "",
                    "Content-MD5": "0X493GkdoXENg7klv3zR8g==",
                    "Cache-Control": "",
                    "Content-Disposition": "",
                    "BlobType": "BlockBlob",
                    "AccessTier": "Hot",
                    "AccessTierInferred": "true",
                    "LeaseStatus": "unlocked",
                    "LeaseState": "available",
                    "ServerEncrypted": "true"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "NextMarker": "",
    "_ServiceEndpoint": "https://{account}.blob.core.windows.net/",
    "_ContainerName": "container-1"
}
```

}

Here some of the results are actual blobs/files while some are directories.
**How can I diffrentiate between a directory and file by looking at responses?**

*PS: Initially i thought content-type of application/octet-stream would be for directories and any other format for blobs/files but that too doesnt work as all xlsx file also have application/octet-stream in response of Azure Data lake Storage.*

Complete NodeJS code is:

```
const request = require('request')
const account = 'add your account here'
const strTime = new Date().toUTCString()
const containerName = 'container-1'

const BearerToken = 'Add your token here'

const options = {
  url: `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}?comp=list&restype=container&prefix=directory-1/&delimiter=`,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${BearerToken}`,
    'x-ms-date': strTime, // var strTime = new Date().toUTCString();
    'x-ms-version': '2019-02-02' // Stable xms version
  }
}

function callback (error, response, body) {
  if (error) console.log(error)
  console.log(body)
}

request(options, callback)
```

Comment: How are you calling the REST API?

Comment: @GauravMantri in NodeJS via request module. I see no method to distinguish or filter blobs from directories while making the request also no method to do that after getting the response. There is no field in response properties which says where the result is a directory or a blob

Comment: Can you share the code please? Also include the package you are using.

Comment: @GauravMantri Shared the code

Comment: Thanks. Please try by changing your request URL to `https://{account}.blob.core.windows.net/container-1?comp=list&restype=container&prefix=directory-1/&maxresults=100&delimiter=/`. You should see `BlobPrefix` element in the response. Your folders should be listed there. Basically I added `delimiter=/` parameter in the request.

Comment: @GauravMantri it worked could you add the same as an answer. So that I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you will need to add `delimiter=/` parameter to your request. So your request would be something like:

```
https://{account}.blob.core.windows.net/container-1?comp=list&restype=container&prefix=directory-1/&maxresults=100&delimiter=/
```

When you request includes the `delimiter` parameter you will see the virtual folders/directories returned under `BlobPrefix` element in the response.

Please see this link to learn more about the delimiter parameter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs#remarks ("Using a Delimiter to Traverse the Blob Namespace" section).